# hibernate eagerly load an association that's normally lazy

Tags: java, hibernate

I have these 2 mappings:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="sample.Operator" table="OPERATOR">
        <id name="id" >
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name"  not-null="true">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        <set name="pointCodes" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key>
                <column name="OperatorID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="sample.PointCode" />
        </set>
    </class>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="sample.PointCode" table="POINTCODE">
  <id name="id">
   <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <properties name="pointCodeKey" unique="true">
   <property name="pointCode" not-null="true">
   </property>
   <property name="networkIndicator" not-null="true">
   </property>
  </properties>
  <property name="name" not-null="true">
  </property>
 </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

Most of the time when featching an Operator I want the pointCodes to be fetched lazily, so I don't want to set lazy="false" in the mappings,

However I have one query, e.g. `session.createQuery("from Operator").list()` where I do want the pointCodes association to NOT be fetched lazily - how do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hibernate reference manual [writes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins):

> A "fetch" join allows associations or
>   collections of values to be
>   initialized along with their parent
>   objects using a single select. This is
>   particularly useful in the case of a
>   collection. It effectively overrides
>   the outer join and lazy declarations
>   of the mapping file for associations
>   and collections. See Section 20.1,
>   “Fetching strategies” for more
>   information.
>
> ```
> from Cat as cat
>     inner join fetch cat.mate
>     left join fetch cat.kittens
> ```
>
> A fetch join does not usually need to
>   assign an alias, because the
>   associated objects should not be used
>   in the where clause (or any other
>   clause). The associated objects are
>   also not returned directly in the
>   query results. Instead, they may be
>   accessed via the parent object. The
>   only reason you might need an alias is
>   if you are recursively join fetching a
>   further collection:
>
> ```
> from Cat as cat
>     inner join fetch cat.mate
>     left join fetch cat.kittens child
>     left join fetch child.kittens
> ```
>
> The fetch construct cannot be used in
>   queries called using iterate() (though
>   scroll() can be used). Fetch should be
>   used together with setMaxResults() or
>   setFirstResult(), as these operations
>   are based on the result rows which
>   usually contain duplicates for eager
>   collection fetching, hence, the number
>   of rows is not what you would expect.
>   Fetch should also not be used together
>   with impromptu with condition. It is
>   possible to create a cartesian product
>   by join fetching more than one
>   collection in a query, so take care in
>   this case. Join fetching multiple
>   collection roles can produce
>   unexpected results for bag mappings,
>   so user discretion is advised when
>   formulating queries in this case.
>   Finally, note that full join fetch and
>   right join fetch are not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference sake, I ran into something like this once, where hibernate was always eagerly loading a set for me.

Turns out I had this setter:

```
public void setStreams(Set<StreamRef> streams) {
  for (StreamRef s : (Set<StreamRef>) streams) {
    s.setTape(this); // boo on hibernate, which apparently needs this. whoa!
  }
this.streams = streams;
}
```

which was being called by hibernate (passing it a pointer to a lazy set) but then my for loop was basically calling it to be loaded at that point.  If that helps any followers :)

You can test if it's lazy by closing the session, then trying to iterate over the collection.  If it's lazy, you'll get `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: XX.streams, no session or session was closed`